# И вновь регулярки (парсинг)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер

```
><!-- Begin Topic Entry 1053094 -->
<tr> 
    <td align="center" class="row1" id='tid-folder-1053094' onclick='return topic_toggle_folder("1053094");'><img src='style_images/ibrstyle/f_norm_no.gif' border='0'  alt='Нет новых сообщений' /></td>
    <td align="center" class="row1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="row1" valign="middle">
        <div style='float:right'></div>
        <div>
             <a href="#" onclick="PopUp('http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?act=attach&amp;code=showtopic&amp;tid=1053094', 'Attach1053094', 500,400); return false;" title="1 прикрепленные файлы: Просмотр"><img src='style_images/ibrstyle/attachicon.gif' border='0'  alt='Тема имеет прикрепленные файлы' /></a><span id='tid-span-1053094'><a id="tid-link-1053094" href="http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showtopic=1053094" title="Тема создана: Вчера, 23:08">Культ Изоленты</a></span> &nbsp;<a href="javascript:multi_page_jump('http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showtopic=1053094', 40, 20 );" title="Переход по страницам"><img src='style_images/ibrstyle/pages_icon.gif' alt='*' border='0' /></a> <span class="minipagelink"><a href="http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showtopic=1053094&amp;st=0">1</a></span><span class="minipagelink"><a href="http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showtopic=1053094&amp;st=20">2</a></span>
            <div class="desc"><span onclick='return span_desc_to_input("1053094");' id='tid-desc-1053094'></span></div>Куратор темы: <a href="./index.php?showuser=361702">Дарк_найт</a>        </div>
    </td>
    <td align='center' class="row2">
     <a href="javascript:who_posted(1053094);">39</a>    </td>
    <td align="center" class="row2"><a href='http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showuser=361702'>Дарк_найт</a></td>
    <td align="center" class="row2">316</td>
    <td class="row2"><span class="lastaction">Сегодня, 11:11<br /><a href="http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showtopic=1053094&amp;view=getlastpost">Посл. сообщение:</a> <b><a href='http://forum.sibnet.ru/index.php?showuser=119715'>woopy</a></b></span></td></tr>
<!-- End Topic Entry 1053094 -->
```

Вот такие куски кода распиханы на странице (форум, по 20 штук на странице). Мне нужно все их спарсить и поместить в список. Мой код:

```
 req = urllib.request.urlopen(a)
            print('Заходим на страницу '+str(num))
            page = req.read()
            res = page.decode('windows-1251')           
            topics = re.findall(r'<!-- Begin Topic Entry(.*)<!-- End Topic Entry', res)
            print('Проверка')           
            for i in topics:
                print(i+'\n')
```

На выходе я получаю абсолютно пустой список. Что же я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- topics = re.findall(r'<!-- Begin Topic Entry(.*)<!-- End Topic Entry', res)
+ topics = re.findall(r'<!-- Begin Topic Entry(.*)<!-- End Topic Entry', res, re.DOTALL)
```

[re.DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)

> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.